# jQuery Accessing a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get the following back from an `$.ajax({ POST.....`

```
[{"total_votes":1,"options":[{"id":40,"vote_count":0,"users":[]},{"id":41,"vote_count":1,"users":[{"photo":"xxxxxxxxxxx.png","name":"XXXXX,"id":1}]},{"id":42,"vote_count":0,"users":[]}]}]
```

so I try to get total_votes with:

```
    success: function(e) {
        console.log(e['total_votes'])       
    }
```

also try to get

```
        console.log( e['options'].length() )
        console.log( e['options'][0]['id'] )
```

Suggestions on why I keep getting undefined? Also is there a better way to loop through options?

Thanks

Comment: You excluded some important details from your `$.ajax()` method. Did you set the `dataType:` property to `'json'`? If not, is it being sent from the server with the proper headers?

Comment: @AnApprentce, I think ur Json is not correctly formatted. you may need to check the returned type using firbugs in firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your root object is an array, so you would need to do something like `e[0]['total_votes']`. Also the length of an array is not a function its a property so you would want to do `e[0].options.length` or `e[0]['options'].length`.

Comment: @AnApprentice: Works if your JSON is parsed: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/aJNCm/. Parse it or set `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: Is the data being parsed as json or a string? What happens if you set  dataType: "json" in the options section? (See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

Loop through them with [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 1):

It would be `e[0].total_votes` according to your example JSON response (it's in an array).

Comment: @AnApprentice: Did you make sure to define the `dataType` as `"json"`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call JSON.parse before dereferencing the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

Formatted ur Json this way, you can get the "total_votes" value like this

```
success: function(e) {
    console.log(e[0].total_votes);

}

 [
    {
        "total_votes": 1,
        "options": [
            {
                "id": 40,
                "vote_count": 0,
                "users": []
            },
            {
                "id": 41,
                "vote_count": 1,
                "users": [
                    {
                        "photo": "xxxxxxxxxxx.png",
                        "name": "XXXXX",
                        "id": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 42,
                "vote_count": 0,
                "users": [
                    {}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

check out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tsegay/WR2ZT/17/)